# dynamically create subdomain path for images

Tags: php, image, path, subdomain

I'm looking for a PHP script that will rewrite my image paths to a subdomain. I currently have a script that performs this action, but it's difficult to use on my local development. Here is my current script:

```
<?php
$IMG_BASE_URL1="http://img.mysite.com/";
?>
```

...and then for the image...

```
<img src="<?php echo $IMG_BASE_URL1; ?>images/ui/logo.png">
```

This works great but it doesn't allow me to see the images locally while I'm developing the page. Is there a way to globally load the images from my subdomain without including `<?php echo $IMG_BASE_URL1; ?>` in the src path?

Comment: Doesn't `http://img.mysite.com/` map to a folder called `img` which can also be accessed like this: `http://mysite.com/img/`?

Comment: That looks a lot like a constant, so you may as well use `define()`.

Comment: Nick, the goal is to speed up load time by accessing two domains (www.mysite.com and img.mysite.com) in parallel, even though they point to the same source. Linking to mysite.com/img doesn't achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Apache (?) you could setup a virtual host to simulate your subdomain.

Here's a nice article on it, I've done it a few days ago: http://apptools.com/phptools/virtualhost.php

Comment: Basically, it boils down to the fact that I am lazy and I want to see the elements within Dreamweaver. I have a virtual server running on my machine, but this requires me to switch from Dreamweaver to my browser so see any image changes. It would also be nice to have EVERY image automatically pulled from the subdomain rather than manually adding <?php echo $IMG_BASE_URL1; ?> to the src of each image.